# Error messages at bootup

Tags: permissions, kde

Running ubuntu 14:10 and the following three dialog boxes appear with errors in them.

### My hard drive is 500gb and its a fresh install of ubuntu.

**Dialog box**
Error - Run Command Interface
Unable to save bookmarks in
/home/joseph/.kde/share/apps/kfileplaces/bookmarks.xml.

Reported error was: insufficient permissions in target directory
This error message will only be shown once. The cause of the error needs to be fixed as quickly 
as possible, which is most likely a full hard drive.

---

**Second Dialog box**
Error - Plasma Desktop Shell <2>
Unable to save bookmarks in
/home/joseph/.kde/share/apps/kfileplaces/bookmarks.xml.

### Reported error was: insufficient permissions in target directory  This error needs to be fixed as quickly as possible, which is most likely a full hard drive.

**Third Dialog Box**
Error - Plasma Desktop Shell
Unable to save bookmarks in 
/home/joseph/.kde/share/apps/kfileplaces/bookmarks.xml.

### Reported error was: insufficient permission in target directory. This error message will be shown only once. The cause of the error needs to be fixed as quickly as possible, which is most likely a full hard drive.

On click OK on all three of these dialog boxed the OS then continues to bootup successfully. but im no expert in this and have no idea what these mean and how to resolve them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, really do check file permissions,may be something changed them. May be you tried to run KDE app with sudo? 
Anyway, `chown -R <username> ~/.kde` will not hurt. First try it without sudo, to see if there really were forbidden files.

Comment: That solved the problem, i ran the first command with out sudo and there was a whole list, ran again with sudo, requested password and did nothing, rebooting the computer and all is well.  Thank you

Comment: Never run GUI programs with `sudo` as it may lock access to your user prefrences files.